# Problem compiling JOS - undefined reference to `__udivdi3' and `__umoddi3'

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc

I'm taking a class on operating systems this semester and have ran into a problem while setting everything up.

I cloned the git repository for the JOS operating system and would like to try to compile everything and run it in qemu.

The problem is that when I type make `qemu-gdb` it lists some files that it managed to compile, but runs into a problem when compiling `printfmt.c`

The error is:

```
obj/kern/printfmt.o: In function `printnum':
lib/printfmt.c:41: undefined reference to `__udivdi3'
lib/printfmt.c:49: undefined reference to `__umoddi3'
make: *** [obj/kern/kernel] Error 1
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS 64bit and GCC 4.8.

As far as I understand, it has something to do with division and some lib files, but I have absolutely no idea what to do about it since I'm still pretty much a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the 32-bit gcc multilib, try installing the gcc-multilib package using the software manager or `apt-get install gcc-4.8-multilib`

Comment: Yes, it seems that that was it. Thank you very much!